# Apache Spark - map and filter and take(1)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I know the usage of map and filter transformations, but I want to clarify something, map change the content of every element of an rdd one by one, if I use myrdd.map().filter().take(1) the map() function stops when the first element pass the filter function? Or does the whole map() function execute, then the filter takes action?
I'm trying to transform every rdd element and if an element satisfying a condition then the map() function stops and return the element.

Comment: My best guess,  lazy evaluation will be in place and when the first record pass filter, it is done

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD) seems to hint that there is no shortcut, and that the entire `map` and `filter` is executed.

> Take the first num elements of the RDD.
>
> It works by first scanning one partition, and use the results from
> that partition to estimate the number of additional partitions needed
> to satisfy the limit.
>
> Translated from the Scala implementation in RDD#take().
>
> Note this method should only be used if the resulting array is
> expected to be small, as all the data is loaded into the driver’s
> memory.